# How do I make all files executable that have the file extension .cgi?

Tags: ubuntu, file-permissions

My server downloads its files from git hub to make sure they are up to date and make it easier for me to edit the files. I have set up a cron job that will update the files every few minutes.

However I am having a problem as the CGI files that are being added to the repository do not have the right permissions so they are unable to be executed. I know that

```
sudo chmod +x *.cgi
```

Will make the files executable, but the files lie across multiple directories. Is there a way that I can do this in one command. Something along the lines of:

```
sudo chmod +x */*.cgi
```

Comment: Use `find` to get the relevant files, and then pipe the result through to `chmod` … similar to what’s suggested here, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions#Recursive_chmod_using_find.2C_pipemill.2C_and_sudo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to combine *find* with *chmod*:

```
sudo find /path/to/files -name "*.cgi" -exec chmod +x {} \;
```